# Getting Subscription out of range Error

Tags: vba

Code is running well while checking if "Test_Worksheet" worksheet exists in workbook file opened by dialog. Workbook File is opening correctly & if "Test_Worksheet" sheet exists in that file then debug.print (in Sub ChkSalfile)  give "Name is True".

But if sheet not available in Workbook, then "Subscription out of  Range" error coming. Please help. My code is as below

```
Sub Main()

    Dim salefor As Workbook
    Dim salpathfileName As String, salfileName As String
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With fd
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Please select file."
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel 2003", "*.xls?"
        .InitialFileName = "*SAL*.*"

        result4 = .Show

        If (result4 <> 0) Then
            salfileName = Dir(.SelectedItems(1))
            salpathfileName = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
           'if user pressed CANCEL - exit sub
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            MsgBox "User pressed CANCEL"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    Set salefor = Workbooks.Open(salfileName, ReadOnly:=True)

    Call ChkSalfile(salfileName, salefor)

End Sub


Sub ChkSalfile (salfileName As String, salefor As Workbook)

    Dim chksalsheet As String

    chksalsheet = DoesWorkSheetExist("Test_Worksheet", salfileName)
    If chksalsheet = True Then
        Debug.Print "Name is " & chksalsheet
    Else
        Debug.Print "File not found"
    End If

End Sub


Option Explicit

Public Function DoesWorkSheetExist(WorkSheetName As String, Optional WorkBookName As String)

    Dim WS As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
    If WorkBookName = vbNullString Then
        Set WS = Sheets(WorkSheetName)
    Else
        Set WS = Workbooks(WorkBookName).Sheets(WorkSheetName)
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    DoesWorkSheetExist = Not WS Is Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: which line is throwing "Subscription out of Range" error?

Comment: Error appears when "Test_worksheet" done not exists. I think çhksalsheet  (under chkSalFile sub) variable not getting defined when no worksheet found.

Comment: which line is throwing that error? click "Debug" button in the error message box and you are brought to that line which is highlighted also

Comment: The code doesn't work, it has compile errors due to undefined result4 variable.  I tried to salvage something from it but after 30 minutes editing I was no closer to a reasonable question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your settings in the VBA project editor are set to break on any errors. Change this setting to break only on unhandled errors:

```
Tools --> Options --> General Tab --> Error Trapping --> check "Break on Unhadled Errors"
```

That said, don't `Dim` your variable as a `String` when it is a `Boolean`:

```
Dim chksalsheet As Boolean ' <-- Not as String
```